# Determine which prepared statement causes an error in a try/catch

Tags: php, oop, pdo, try-catch

In the catch clause, how do I determine which prepared statement caused the error so that I could apply debugDumpParams on it?  See the below example.

```
$p1=db::db()->prepare("INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (:a,:b,:c)");
$p2=db::db()->prepare("INSERT INTO t2 (a,b,c) VALUES (:a,:b,:c)");
try{
    $data=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3);
    $p1->execute($data);
    $p2->execute($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    //Display debugDumpParams() for the statement that caused the error
}
```

Comment: comment out and try one at a time

Comment: Separate try-catch for each

Comment: @cmorrissey.  Not ideal as I want a generic catch for all queries.

Comment: @MarkM  Yea, I could but it sure adds a bunch of code.  Didn't know if a better solution was possible.

Comment: There might be a better way - I'm not sure. But if you have a bunch of queries you could put them in a loop and `prepare` and `execute` each with a try-catch. Wouldn't be much more code.

Answer (score 1):

To determine which query fails execute them in different try catch blocks.

```
$data=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3);

$p1 = db::db()->prepare("INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (:a,:b,:c)");
try {    
    $p1->execute($data);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Display debugDumpParams() for the statement that caused the error
    // First query has failed
}
$p2 = db::db()->prepare("INSERT INTO t2 (a,b,c) VALUES (:a,:b,:c)");
try {    
    $p2->execute($data);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Display debugDumpParams() for the statement that caused the error
    // Second query has failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check [error code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php) of each statement. (read documentation about codes of your DB). null means that statement was not executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to catch PDOException you might as well include prepare() in the try catch, and you should also  use one query to inserts if possible.

Prepare returns false when it fails so check the value of $p and throw exception